Problem with swiftgen on GitHub CI after updating action/cache version
I updated on the GitHub CI the workflow action/cache from 3.2.4 to 4.0.2. The test run for the PR with these changes is now failing when trying to build with xcodebuild.
Package resolution works fine but when it comes to the build script where swiftgen is triggered this error is thrown:
Error: error: 'github.com_swiftgen_swiftgen': Invalid manifest (compiled with: ["/Applications/Xcode_15.4.app/ ...

The used cache is for spam builds and mint. Also swiftgen is used via mint.
Using version 3.2.5 is working fine, from 3.2.6 it is failing.
What I found so far: 'Invalid manifest' might be related to a failing spm package. But I was not able to find anything more.
If anyone has an idea in which direction further investigation would  make sense, please let me know.

To help anyone with similar problems, here is my workaround to solve this problem:
The issue appeared after the Cache action was using a different compression tool (zstd) (3.2.5 -> 3.2.6).
So I uninstall zstd on CI to force the cache tool to use gzip instead:
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies zstd

